# Orbeon: how to preload data through REST api

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm not sure if it worth digging into this ... that's why I ask in advance.

Is it possible or makes it sense at all to preload data into the Orbeon system before sending links to the individual form to a customer? We would do this with the REST api. Preload means that we create an entry via the REST api with all relevant customer data (customer number, name, address, ...). Then we send a link with the form id to the customer and ask him to complete the missing data (product order, address check, ...).

As I can't find a helpful example for this approach I'm unsure if Orbeon is the right tool for such a scenario.

Thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Currently Orbeon doesn't support this feature, see [RFE #3080](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3080).

As a workaround I use [xxf:get-request-parameter()](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas-examples.html#set-the-value-of-a-field-from-a-url-parameter) to supply a parameter for a [database service](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/database-services.html).